# How to mark file as resolved using local/remote version

Tags: mercurial

I pulled one revision and tried to merge but hg couldn't make the merge. I know the right version is the local (or the remote...), so I do this:

```
hg heads
hg revert file_path --rev right_rev
hg resolve -m file_path
...
```

Is there an easier way to do this?
Yes I know I should open the file, verify, manually resolve, bla bla bla

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With newer versions of Mercurial (1.7.0 and later), you can use `hg merge --tool internal:local` to keep the local version (i.e. the one that's in your working directory), or `hg merge --tool internal:other` to keep the other version.  The `--tool` option was introduced as a shorthand for `--config ui.merge=internal:local`, which was how you did it in older versions of Mercurial.

See the [merge-tools online help](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#merge-tools) or use `hg help merge-tools` at the command-line for more information.

Comment: And you can also use the `--tool` option in the `hg resolve` command to specify the version for *each* conflicted file.

Answer (score 0):

If you know before you're going to merge you can use [this quick trick](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Keep_.22My.22_or_.22Their.22_files_when_doing_a_merge):

to auto select local (or remote) like this:

```
hg --config ui.merge=internal:local merge
```